# UIView cut off in landscape mode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios

I have several UIViews added as subViews to my main view controller. The way I have the views laid out looks fine in portrait mode, however, when it is tilted in to landscape mode, the bottom parts of the subviews gets cut off. I figured if I set the height of the frame, it would allow the screen to scroll and thus reveal the parts of the subViews that were cut off - but it doesn't.

```
- (void)didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification {

    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[notification object] orientation];

    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1024.0, maxHeight);
    } else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1024.0, maxHeight);
    }
}
```

I also tried adding a UIScrollView to the main view, then adding the afore mentioned subViews to the scrollView

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    //add views to scrollView

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

How can I make the main view "scroll" if the sub-views exceed the screen size?

Comment: How do you define `maxHeight`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you add your views to the scroll view, you must set the `contentSize` property of the scroll view so that the scroll view knows there's content to be scrolled to.